# Using Docusign REST API to attach document to SignerAttachmentTab

Tags: docusignapi

We have defined a template that will be filled in and signed by our customers. In this template we have some fields that we pre-populate along with some documents that we will attach. The customer will fill in other fields and attach more documents. We are using the REST API to generate the sign request. We are able to generate the correct REST request to fill the tabs in the template, set the recipients and successfully send the signature request.  All this works great. But now we're trying to get a document attached to the appropriate SignerAttachmentTab in the template and we cannot get REST to accept it.

We've tried using the Documents field but that doesn't work with templates it seems. We created a composite template and then defined a document for the document, server template for the template itself and an inline template to contain the tab data we want to populate. This keeps generating errors about the tab page number not being right. We've tried different values and we've looked over all the forum posts and documentation related to attaching documents to templates and none of them seem to work.

For the document we specify the file to upload, set the document ID and name. In the server template we specify the template ID. In the inline template we create a recipient, set their information, build up the envelope tabs with the data and then add a SignerAttachmentTab for the document. In this tab we set the document ID to match the document ID from the Document element. We set the tabLabel to the label used in the template itself. We've tried setting pagenumber but that doesn't change anything. All we want is for the document to be sent to the customer. When the open it they can double click the attachment field and view the document we're trying to send.

I'm trying to use the recipe explorer to get this to work using raw REST and it keeps failing with the TAB_PAGENUMBER_IS_NOT_IN_DOCUMENT error. It seems like the document is taking precedence over the template. Unfortunately I cannot change the order of the templates in the editor other than setting the sequence # on the server and inline templates. Here's the request that is generated using DocuSign's test system.

```
{ 
    "compositeTemplates":[{
       "document":   {
           "documentBase64":"<Base64BytesHere>",
           "documentId":"2",
           "name":"Test.pdf"
       },
       "inlineTemplates":[{
           "recipients":{
               "signers":[{
                     "email":"abc@def.org",
                     "name":"Person",
                     "recipientId":"1",
                     "roleName":"Sender 1",
                     "tabs":{
                          "signerAttachmentTabs":[{
                               "documentId":"2",
                               "tabLabel":"MyAttachment"
                          }],
                          "textTabs":[{
                               "tabLabel":"someText",
                               "value":"Value1" }
                          ]}
                 }]},
             "sequence":"2"
         }],
         "serverTemplates":[{
               "sequence":"1",
               "templateId":"guid}]
             }],
         "emailBlurb":"A message",
         "emailSubject":"Test",
         "status":"sent"
}
```

I've looked at the existing posts in the forums and either they don't work for my case or they aren't trying to actually attach the documents to the template but simply include them as a document in addition to the template.

Answer (score 3):

## Update

Re:

> ...associate [a] document to the tab so that the signer will be able to click the attachment field in the document and see the document

Yes, you can now do this by using Smart Sections with a [documentHtmlDisplaySettings](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#parameters_documenthtmldisplaysettings) object in the Envelopes:create request. The **collapsed** (or collapsible) section can be displayed in different ways:

- inline
- collapsible
- collapsed
- continue_button
- responsive_table
- responsive_table_single_column
- print_only

### Live examples that you can try online

- [HTML source document](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=HTML%20responsive%20credit%20card%20form%20with%20smart%20sections)
- [Word source document](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Word%20doc%20with%20many%20types%20of%20smart%20sections)

## Original answer

Re:

> But now we're trying to get a document attached to the appropriate SignerAttachmentTab in the template and we cannot get REST to accept it.

You're trying to use the API to add a document to a SignerAttachmentTab?

This is not supported. Only signers themselves add documents to a SignerAttachmentTab. The API can't do it for them.

Is the issue that you want to make sure that a signer attaches (uploads) a document to the envelope as part of the signing ceremony? You can make the tab non-optional (required). But that won't check the contents of the attached file.

You could use a web hook / Connect to check the file(s) that were attached and, if the right files weren't attached, generate another enveloper for the signer.

Comment: No I'm not trying to verify attached documents. As part of the API you can set any data that is defined in the form. We are already doing this for other tabs on the form (ex names). One of the tabs is a document attachment where we can attach documents. That is what I'm trying to do. The API does support attaching documents to the template via composite templates but I'm having a hard time getting Docusign to accept the request and associate the document to the tab so that the signer will be able to click the attachment field in the document and see the document.

Comment: DocuSign does not support the ability to "...associate [a] document to the tab so that the signer will be able to click the attachment field in the document and see the document" We are looking into adding that type of feature but it is not available at this time.

Comment: @LarryK Is it supported now in 2021 ? I have searched through documentation and it looks like it still not supported: "
signerAttachmentTabs [signerAttachment]
A list of Signer Attachment tabs.

This type of tab enables the recipient to attach supporting documents to an envelope. This value can't be set."

Comment: @rzasap -- yes, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. For a template without attachments I was using TemplateRole and EnvelopeTabs. But for attachments, trying to include any document would cause the document to override the template. So I switched to composite template with server and inline templates for the template and data. Trying to add documents in various combinations in the various areas where they are allowed generally caused the request to be sent but with no documents.

The final solution was to go back to the original TemplateRole approach but to create the envelope as a draft. After the draft envelope was created I could then add the document to the envelope. But unfortunately to send the envelope you then have to reattach the recipients. I'm looking to clean that up but otherwise it is working for me now.